# Unable to properly get nested tags in XSLT Translation

Tags: xml, xslt

I am going through a translation and have data that looks like the following:

-MainTag1
---Value One
---Value Two
---SubTag
------SubValue1
------Subvalue2

-MainTag2
---Value Three
---Value Four
---SubTag
------SubValue3
------Subvalue4

When doing a template match, I tried calling the nesting an "apply templates" but am getting a result that has the MainTag1, Value One, Value Two, SubValue1, SubValue2, SubValue3, SubValue4 and it passes over MainTag2, Value Three, and Value Four. The output I would like is the list of values in order they are listed, but I don't want to just get the text (since I am going to add more things to it.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<binder>
<catalog>
<Name> Catalog 1 </Name>
<Page> Page 1 </Page>

  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>

<cd>
<title>One night only</title>
<artist>Bee Gees</artist>
<country>UK</country>
<company>Polydor</company>
<price>10.90</price>
<year>1998</year>
</cd>
</catalog>
<catalog>
<Name> Catalog 2 </Name>
<Page> Page 7 </Page>

<cd>
<title>Big Willie style</title>
<artist>Will Smith</artist>
<country>USA</country>
<company>Columbia</company>
<price>9.90</price>
<year>1997</year>
</cd>

<cd>
<title>Unchain my heart</title>
<artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
<country>USA</country>
<company>EMI</company>
<price>8.20</price>
<year>1987</year>
</cd>


</catalog>
<binder>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:apply-templates select="binder/catalog" />
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="catalog">
<xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
<xsl:value-of select="Page"/>              
<xsl:for-each select="cd">
<xsl:value-of select="title"/>
<xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
<xsl:comment>***Want to reference the "Name" tag again, so I could do something like ("title" rdfs:subClassOf "Name")***</xsl:comment>

</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: Should be: Catalog 1, Page 1, the CDs under that, then Catalog 2, Page 7, the CDs under that

Comment: So you want exactly the same order as given in the source XML, but text only? You should insert the desired output as explicit as possible in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the `text()` nodes in the order that they appear, then remove all of your templates and use the default templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The default processing will match elements and then apply-templates to it's child nodes. The default processing for `text()` will copy it into the output.

The above stylesheet is the equivalent of this one, but has templates to explicitly show what happens by default:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction() | @*"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I was able to do this using apply template, but am not sure how to reference a top level when I am going through the subcategory. I am trying to create RDF and would like to create a subclass relationship.

Comment: It might be easier to assist with a more concrete example of inputs/outputs. You have an abstract definition of structure that doesn't match your XML and XSLT, and output that you described is for a small piece of the final output. From what you had described, it sounded as if you wanted to convert the entire XML into a text rendering, but that doesn't seem to really be what you want to do. The solution to your problem will be different than what I had posted (but it is difficult to know that from the question that you posted)

Comment: I just changed the sample code up top to more accurately reflect what I am trying to do (and added the comment in the XSLT to say what I would like to generate). Hopefully that helps explain it better.